# Out of order rendering of pixel shaders in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I working on some code to help measure and correct for the optical distortion in a head mounted display system. I am doing this by writing two pixel shaders (fragment shaders rendering on a full screen quad) one that generates diffrent test patterns and another that will apply a warp correction. (Right now the warp shader is just a temp pixel shader that rendeders a multicolored quad). My problem is that in my main rendering loop even thought I render the pattern shader quad first and then my dummy test warp shader the pattern shader always apears on top of the warp shader. My code in my main render loop looks like this:

```
 if (showPattern){
   glUseProgram(patternShader->shaderprog);
   //configure shader uniforms
   glBindVertexArray(patternShader->vao);
   glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
   glUseProgram(NULL);
 }

 if (doWarp){
   glUseProgram(warpShader->shaderprog);
   //configure shader uniforms
   glBindVertexArray(warpShader->vao);
   glDrawElements(GLddddd_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
 glUseProgram(NULL);
 }
```

If only showPattern is true then I get the expected output of the patternShader. Likewise if only doWarp is true I get the expected output of the warpShader. However if both are true I get the output of the patternShader on top of the warp shader not the other way around as I expected. If I switch the order of the if blocks I get the opposite effect which I want but I want to understand why it does not work like I think it should.

Comment: This isn't an issue of the invocation order of your shaders. My guess would be that both draw calls draw to the same depth, and your depth test is set appropriately, so it will prevent an otherdraw from your second pass.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the vertex attributes you're rendering, and possibly the shaders doing the rendering. I agree with @derhass that it's probably a depth issue, but it could be a non-obvious one.